# Android remote service executing but onStartCommand never called

Tags: android, service, aidl

So after 2-3 hours of failures i finally got my remote service to work somehow but it's acting real strange.

I'm using AIDL to send mediaPath string to my service and it starts playing music just fine, but the onStartCommand never gets called and the Service entry in Apps doesn't have the label/description I set in the manifest file. [http://i50.tinypic.com/344p349.png]

Also the Service terminates if I terminate the main Activity process, although it resides in a separate process. Is this how it's supposed to be? [http://i49.tinypic.com/16hpa86.png]

And I never get the "Service disconnected" Log which should happen when Service gets unbound from Activity.

Service code:

```
package com.example.randomserviceshitnot;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.util.Log;

public class MojPrviServis extends Service {
    private final Servis.Stub binder = new Servis.Stub() {
        public void execute(String mediaPath) throws RemoteException {
            MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

            try {
                mp.setDataSource(mediaPath);
                mp.prepare();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) { e.printStackTrace(); } catch (SecurityException e) {
                e.printStackTrace(); } catch (IllegalStateException e) { e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
                mp.start();
        }
    };

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d("Filip", "Service onCreate called.");
    }

    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return binder;
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d("Filip ", "Service onStart called.");
        return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

Activity code:

```
package com.example.randomserviceshitnot;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private Servis mBoundService;
    private boolean mIsBound = false;
    private static final String mediaPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Music/Art Of The Dress(Archie Remix).mp3";

    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            Log.d("Filip ", "Service connected."); 
            mBoundService = Servis.Stub.asInterface(service);
            try {
                mBoundService.execute(mediaPath);
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            Log.d("Filip ", "Service disconnected.");
            mBoundService = null;
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        doBindService();
    }

    void doBindService() {
        Intent s = new Intent();
        s.setAction("remote.servis");
        bindService(s, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        mIsBound = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        doUnbindService();
    }

    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        doUnbindService();
    }

    void doUnbindService() {
        if(mIsBound) {
            unbindService(mConnection);
            mIsBound=false;
        }
    }
}
```

AIDL:

```
package com.example.randomserviceshitnot;

interface Servis {
    void execute(String s);
}
```

Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.randomserviceshitnot"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".MojPrviServis"
            android:label="@string/servis_koji_notifikuje"
            android:description="@string/proces_desc"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:process=":dep" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="remote.servis" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: having the same issue myself as well.

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Read the documentation of onStartCommand() and onBind()

When you call bindService() onStartCommand() is NOT called. But onBind() is called.

Also the service terminates if all the clients exited if the service was stared with bindservice().

For playing music you should use startService() instead of bind. If service is started this way then it does not stop when client exists. It has to stop itself when done.